# Prevent position: sticky elements from pushing each other (but rather overlap like position: absolute)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the scrolling-effect of the iOS 16 weather app with CSS. That is to say I need blocks with sticky headers that overlap each other at the top. `position: sticky` itself pushes the last header out once the next header is at the top. Is there a way to prevent this behavior and to have the blocks overlap? (preferably using only CSS)

To make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve here's the weather app I'm talking about. As you can see the next block overlaps the title of the previous block (while it fades away) instead of pushing it out.

[image]

The way I usually do stuff like this is by using `position: sticky`, which pushes the previous block out instead of overlapping it.

```css
section {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: coral;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="header">
        Title 1
    </div>
    <div class="content" />
</section>
<section>
    <div class="header">
        Title 2
    </div>
    <div class="content" />
</section>
<section>
    <div class="header">
        Title 3
    </div>
    <div class="content" />
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a negative bottom margin to the sticky header to give it more room to remain sticky and this will simulate the overlap you want. Don't forget to also add the same amount of margin to the next section to rectify.

```css
section {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: coral;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}
.header + * {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="header">
        Title 1
    </div>
    <div class="content" />
</section>
<section>
    <div class="header">
        Title 2
    </div>
    <div class="content" />
</section>
<section>
    <div class="header">
        Title 3
    </div>
    <div class="content" />
</section>
```

Comment: That works really well and doesn't change the structure of the html. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to alter your structure a bit. Taking the `.header` elements outside the `section` elements would directly have the effect you want. Although it modifies how you can do the styling you want.

```css
section {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: coral;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Title 1
</div>
<section>
  <div class="content" />
</section>

<div class="header">
  Title 2
</div>
<section>
  <div class="content" />
</section>

<div class="header">
  Title 3
</div>
<section>
  <div class="content" />
</section>
```

Comment: While it does change the structure of the html, I can see its benefits. Gonna try both solutions and see which one works better. Thanks!